.Net 8 web application crash after removing old hosting bundle
I had migrated my application from .Net 2 to .Net 5 and installed the .Net 5 hosting bundle and the application runed with no issue.
Now, I migrated to .Net 8 and installed the hosting bundle .Net 8 as well and the application runs with no issue but when I removed the old .Net 2 hosting bundle my application crash with an error 500 ! What dependency with .net 2 and .Net 8 can cause the problem ? because the logs does not really help me
Note that I use IIS 8.5
Thank you

IIS 8.x reached end of life, so not likely others keep it around.

Doesn't mean a related tool is no longer supported that SOF won't answer it. People here have a knowledge for supported and not supported tool.  Also, the answer is not necessarly related to IIS

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
